# cellForItemAt not being called after collectionView.deleteItems

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata

I am successfully deleting items from my collectionView and datasource, but `cellForItemAt` is no being called after the delete, so my indexes are getting messed up. Even if I manually call `collectionView.reloadData()` right after the delete, it does not work.

However, if I call `collectionView.reloadData()` anytime before `collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])`, it will get called, but obviously doesn't do me any good. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, please take a look:

```
class ChipView: UIView {        
    var chips: [ChipModel]?

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
         let flowLayout = LeftAlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout()
         flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical

         let result = UICollectionView(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: flowLayout)
         result.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         result.register(Chip.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
         result.delegate = self
         result.dataSource = self
         result.backgroundColor = .clear
         result.isAccessibilityElement = false
         return result
     }()

    func deleteItem(_ sender: Chip) {
        guard let chipsArray = chips, !chipsArray.isEmpty, let indexPath = sender.indexPath else { return }

        // 1. remove value from source of truth
        chips?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        // 2. delete item from collection view
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
        // TODO: - Figure out why cellForItemAt isn't getting called after collectionView.deleteItems... Needs to update the indexPath
        collectionView.reloadData()
     }

extension ChipView: UICollectionViewDataSource {
     public func collectionView(_: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
         return chips?.count ?? 0
}

     public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Chip
         cell.indexPath = indexPath

         if let chip = chips?[indexPath.row] {
            cell.setupChip(title: chip.title, icon: chip.icon, chipState: chip.chipState)
         }

         return cell
     }
  }
```

Comment: Your mistake is to assign the index path to the cell. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why do we need cell.indexPath in the first place?

I am assuming that you are using `indexPath` value later on some button tap inside the cell to get the model value from dataSource `chips?[indexPath.row]`.

If the answer is yes, then I can think one way to avoid this could be as simple as this.

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TruChip
    
    /* Stop doing this
    cell.indexPath = indexPath
    */

    if let chip = chips?[indexPath.row] {
        /* Stop doing this
        cell.setupTruChip(title: chip.title, icon: chip.icon, chipState: chip.chipState)
        */
        cell.setupTruChip(chip)
    }

    return cell
}

/// Inside the cell
class TruChip: UICollectionViewCell {
    var currentChip: TruChipModel?

    func setupTruChip(_ chip: TruChipModel) {
        currentChip = chip
        self.setupTruChip(title: chip.title, icon: chip.icon, chipState: chip.chipState)
    }
}
```

With this approach, you can completely eliminate the need to remember `indexPath` on a cell. The cell remembers the current model data that it is representing on the UI.

Comment: Thanks, I knew something didn't look right with the IndexPath when I inherited this project, but it is what it is.... I'll have to refactor quite a bit to make this change but I'll come back once I validate that it works.

Comment: I refactored and removed the indexPath from cell. However, the original issue persists, so I am still using collectionView.performBatchUpdates, which is still working for my use case.

Comment: *you have to do it like this.* Why? There is only **one** operation (the signature implies update**s**, plural) and this does not call `itemForRow` anyway. `performBatchUpdates` is for **multiple** simultaneous `insert`/`delete` and `move` operations

Answer (score -2):

Adding batch updates before the delete fixed it for me:

```
    collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
        collectionView.deleteItems(at: [indexPath])
    } completion: { (finished) in
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```